# flutter firestore show data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

hello, i have cards and the name and surname of the person writes in it.when i click the button next to it, i want it to navigate to another page and in big card  writes the whole information about that person saved in firebase(name,surname,medicine,illness etc).i did the navigate part, can you help me?

```
return Dismissible(
                                onDismissed: (_) {
                                  data.docs[index].reference.delete();
                                },
                                key: UniqueKey(),
                                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                                background: Container(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.delete,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ),
                                child: Card(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    trailing: Wrap(
                                      children: [
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        UpdatePatient()));
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        ShowPatient()));
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    title:
                                        Text("${data.docs[index]["name"]}"),
                                    subtitle: Text(
                                        "${data.docs[index]["surname"]}"),
                                  ),
```

Comment: Have you implemented it? Are you getting any errors? What is the help you need with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the **Id** of the patient you click on to the other page(ShowPatient()) and then accept that **id** from the **ShowPatient()** screen and with that **Id** you will have to **filter** the list which you have all the patients and then **get** the patient that you want with the **Id** that you have, that is the basic logic that you need to implement,

You can refer to this [repo](https://github.com/NiiTyy/UserManager-FlutterApp) for a more practical and clean way to do this.